# brackish water aquarium

Tags: real-analysis

So I have a $10$ gallon aquarium slightly salty aquarium...

When I add water the water is at $.7$% salt. ($7$ part per thousand)

I let $1$ gallon evaporate, at which point I have a $\frac{7}{9}$% salinity
I then drain $1$ additional gallon. now I have $8$ gallons of $\frac{7}{9}$% salinity water.

I then replace the missing $2$ gallons with $.7$% salinity water again.

If I perform this over and over does the water continue to get ever saltier, or does it approach some limit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your 10 gallons of (pure) water weighs 37.85 kg.  Then to reach 0.7% salinity you'd add $0.26495$ kg of salt.

Let's call this amount of salt $x$.  If you add two gallons water with this salinity, you'll be adding $x/5$.  If the initial salinity is different, then it will be some non-negative fraction of $x$, $y = ax$, where $a \geq 0$.

One-ninth of the salt leaves the aquarium by the time it gets down to eight gallons.  (One gallon evaporates, leaving nine gallons still with the original amount of salt.  One gallon is drained, taking one-ninth of the water, and one-ninth of the salt.)

Call $S(n)$ the amount of salt after $n$ cycles.  So if $S(0) = y$, then

$$S(1) = \frac{8}{9}y + \frac{x}{5},$$

or more generally,

$$S(n) = \frac{8}{9}S(n-1) + \frac{x}{5},$$

so that

$$S(n) = \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n S(0) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^k = \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n S(0) + \frac{9x}{5} \left(1 - \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n\right).$$

If $S(0) = ax$, then

$$S(n) = \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n \left[\left(a - \frac{9}{5}\right)x\right] + \frac{9x}{5}.$$

Hence, regardless of the initial concentration, you'll end up with about 80% stronger salinity by doing what you're doing ($S(n) \to \frac{9x}{5}$ as $n \to \infty$).  If $a > \frac{9}{5}$, the concentration will decrease over time.  If $a < \frac{9}{5}$, it will increase over time.

Answer (score 0):

Hint the final concentration of one cycle will be: $$f(x) =.8(\frac{10x}{9})+.2(.7)$$ where $x$ is $.7$ initially.

Does $f(x)$ increase or decrease for each $x$?

Is there any case where $f(x)=x$?

If you can, look at the derivative of $f(x)$.